# SUMIF SQL VIA OLEDB in VB.NET

Tags: sql, vb.net, sum, oledb, oledbcommand

I want sumif results in the database "GSGTS/t3" in the "BLC" column with the number criteria in the "PNM" column. I haven't been able to create sql for the sumif process. With the explanation below :

- the result of the value of 185000 for the number in the column "PNM" which is 1000

```
QTY  CIU        DPR
10    100000     5   =10X10000X(1-5/100)= 95000
5     20000      10  =5X20000X(1-10/100)= 95000
TOTAL                =185000
```

```
GSDTS AS t1                 
PNM     ITM        QTY  CIU    NOD  DPR
1000    TEST 1000   10  10000   01  5
1000    TEST 1001   5   20000   02  10
1002    TEST 1000   12  10000   01  15
1002    TEST 1001   6   20000   02  6

GSGTS AS t3                             
CSB GDN             PNM      DTS     DUD    SAC  DIS    BLC  DIS2
    A.04.01.002.001 1000    13-May-22       01-01           
    A.04.01.002.001 1002    13-May-22       01-02           
result                              
GSGTS AS t3                             
CSB GDN              PNM    DTS       DUD   SAC  DIS    BLC    DIS2
    A.04.01.002.001 1000    13-May-22       01-01       185000  
    A.04.01.002.001 1002    13-May-22       01-02       214800
```

```vb
Private Sub fillDataGridView3()
        Try
            'Dim query As String = "select PNM, sum((qty*ciu)*(1-dpr/100)) AS BLC from GSDTS group by PNM"
 Dim sql As String = "update GSGTS SET BLC=( select sum((qty*ciu)*(1-dpr/100.0)) from GSDTS t2 WHERE GSGTS.[PNM] = t2.[PNM] ) WHERE GDN = 'A.04.01.002.001';"
            Using con As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection(cn)
                Using cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(query, con)
                    'cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CODE", ComboBox1.SelectedValue)
                    Using da As New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)
                        Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable()
                        da.Fill(dt)
                        da.Dispose()
                        source3.DataSource = dt
                        Me.DataGridView3.DataSource = source3
                        Me.DataGridView3.Refresh()
                    End Using
                End Using
            End Using
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try
    End Sub
Sub UpdateGsgts()
    Try
        'Dim sql As String = "update GSGTS as t3 inner join GSDTS as t2 on t3.[PNM] = t2.[PNM] set t3.[BLC] = [CIU] WHERE GDN = 'A.04.01.002.001'AND PNM=@PNM"
           Dim sql As String = "select PNM, sum((qty*ciu)*(1-dpr/100)) AS BLC from GSDTS group by PNM"
        Using conn As New OleDbConnection(cn),
               cmd As New OleDbCommand(sql, conn)
               'cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PNM", ComboBox1.SelectedValue)
            conn.Open()
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        End Using

    Catch myerror As OleDbException
        MessageBox.Show("Error: " & myerror.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

[image: DATABASE WITH RESULT]
[image: syntax error (missing operator)]
[image: RESULT]

[image: error operation must use an updateable query]

Comment: Can't open your attachment. Please share sample data and desired output in text format.

Comment: @KaziMohammadAliNur , I have updated as you requested

Answer (score 3):

You can calculate `PNM` wise `BLC` as below:

Schema and insert statements:

```
 create table GSDTS ( PNM int, ITM varchar(100), QTY int, CIU int, NOD int, DPR int);
 insert into GSDTS values(1000,    'TEST 1000',   10,  10000,   01,  5);
 insert into GSDTS values(1000,    'TEST 1001',   5,   20000,   02,  10);
 insert into GSDTS values(1002,    'TEST 1000',   12,  10000,   01,  15);
 insert into GSDTS values(1002,    'TEST 1001',   6,   20000,   02,  6);
```

Query:

```
 select PNM, sum((qty*ciu)*(1-dpr/100)) BLC from GSDTS
 group by PNM
```

Output:

| PNM | BLC |
| --- | --- |
| 1000 | 185000.0000 |
| 1002 | 214800.0000 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c6bf68e50cac5f4aea4c974ef1d64c4f)*

Update query:

Schema and insert statements:

```
create table GSDTS ( PNM int, ITM varchar(100), QTY int, CIU int, NOD int, DPR int);
   insert into GSDTS values(1000,    'TEST 1000',   10,  10000,   01,  5);
   insert into GSDTS values(1000,    'TEST 1001',   5,   20000,   02,  10);
   insert into GSDTS values(1002,    'TEST 1000',   12,  10000,   01,  15);
   insert into GSDTS values(1002,    'TEST 1001',   6,   20000,   02,  6);
   
   
   create table GSGTS (GDN varchar(50), PNM int, BLC int);
   insert into GSGTS values('A.04.01.002.001',1000,    0);
   insert into GSGTS values('A.04.01.002.001',1002,    0);
```

Select from GSGTS table:

```
 select * from GSGTS
```

Output:

```
| GDN             |  PNM | BLC
| :-------------- | ---: | --:
| A.04.01.002.001 | 1000 |   0
| A.04.01.002.001 | 1002 |   0
```

Update query:

```
update GSGTS SET BLC=( select sum((qty*ciu)*(1-dpr/100.0)) from GSDTS t2 WHERE GSGTS.[PNM] = t2.[PNM] ) WHERE GDN = 'A.04.01.002.001';
```

Select from GSGTS table after update:

```
select * from GSGTS
```

Output:

```
| GDN             |  PNM |    BLC
| :-------------- | ---: | -----:
| A.04.01.002.001 | 1000 | 185000
| A.04.01.002.001 | 1002 | 214800
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=230f8bde91f066f10e51530322913e72)*

Comment: sorry if I am late replying to you, thank you reply reply from you but I have an error `syntax error (missing operator)`. I have also updated in the code and updated screenshots is there something wrong with my code?

Comment: You have added a parameter but never used it in sql. Please check.

Comment: `select PNM, sum((qty*ciu)*(1-dpr/100)) AS BLC from GSDTS group by PNM` from sql you are correct but with the addition of `AS' but can only be used as a view so I want it to be able to update. I have also updated the code and screenshots of the results

Comment: Please mention your dbms name with version.

Comment: ,I use dBase IV with provider "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0"

Comment: I have updated the sql code from you but there is an error 'error operation must use an updateable query '. you can see code updates from me and also screenshots

Comment: I am not an expert on dBase or VB.net but it seems that you are using update query while showing the data and using select query when you need to update. Please check. Screenshots are not accessible.

Comment: @Jack please look into below link: https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/442585/operation-must-use-an-updateable-query-ms-access